# Why does #match return the correct result, but #scan finds only only one letter?

Tags: regex, ruby, string, backreference

### Background for Question

I'm using Ruby 3.2.1, and I know that changes have been made to Ruby's regexp engine. That may or may not be relevant here. However, I get unexpectedly different behavior from [String#match](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/String.html#method-i-match) and [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/String.html#method-i-scan) when using backreferences, and I don't understand why. See example code below.

### My Examples, with Comments and Expectations

###### Working Result with Match

```rb
# Using #match finds the longest string of
# repeated letters, and the letter that is
# repeated.
"gjhfgfcttttdfs".match /(\p{alpha})\1{2,}/
=> #<MatchData "tttt" 1:"t">
```

###### Non-Working, Unexpected Result with Scan

```rb
# Here, #scan returns only a single sub-
# array with a single letter, which is
# the correct letter. However, I was
# expecting an array-of-arrays with all
# repeated letters.
"gjhfgfcttttdfs".scan /(\p{alpha})\1{2,}/
=> [["t"]]
```

### Clarifying the Question

Assuming the problem exists between the keyboard and chair, why is String#scan not returning more matches, or even a single longer match? I'm assuming it's a mistake on my part in the capture expression, but I can't really figure out what I did wrong here.

Comment: I think the problem starts with the "If the pattern contains groups, each result is an array containing one entry per group" part of `String#scan`. Seems that `scan` gives you `'t'` because of the grouping and only `'t'` because that's the only part that matches with the back-reference. `'gjhfgfffcttttdfs'` for example will give you two single-character results from `scan`.

Comment: FWIW, I get the same results in Ruby 2.7, so I don't think you have discovered a breaking change in Ruby.

Comment: @muistooshort You're probably right, and if there are groups then #scan basically returns the value of each group as part of a sub-array, but I suppose I'm also asking "If it's not an obvious mistake on my part, how could I get #scan to return the results I'm expecting?" I'm getting the right answer with #match, but it seems like there should be a way to do the same thing with #scan somehow if I can get the right back-references to the right groupings. It seems like they should both be able to return similar results when used correctly.

Comment: Note that the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) that has one argument and no block can be used in place of `scan` when `gsub`'s argument is a regular expression with one or more capture groups but, unlike `scan`, capture groups have no special meaning in terms of return values. Here `"gjhfgfcttttdfs".gsub(/(\p{alpha})\1{2,}/).to_a #= ["tttt"]`. This form of `gsub` returns an enumerator that simply generates matches of `gsub`'s argument (and has nothing to do with string substitution, despite the method's name).

Answer (score 2):

> If the pattern contains groups, each result is an array containing one
> entry per group.
> *https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/string#method-i-scan*

Seems a little vague, but I think it's been this way for a long time.

```
>> "aaabccc".match /(\p{alpha})\1{2,}/
=> #<MatchData "aaa" 1:"a">
>> "aaabccc".scan /(\p{alpha})\1{2,}/
=> [["a"], ["c"]]
```

To get the whole match, you can capture it, to be part of `scan` results:

```
>> "aaabccc".match /((\p{alpha})\2{2,})/
=> #<MatchData "aaa" 1:"aaa" 2:"a">
#                    ^       ^
# two captures will return two captured results for each match
>> "aaabccc".scan /((\p{alpha})\2{2,})/
=> [["aaa", "a"], ["ccc", "c"]]

# that's the best i could come up with this
>> "aaabccc".scan(/((\p{alpha})\2{2,})/).map(&:first)
=> ["aaa", "ccc"]
```

Full match is only available from the `scan` block:

```
>> a = []; "aaabccc".scan(/(\p{alpha})\1{2,}/) { a << $& }; a
=> ["aaa", "ccc"]
```

Comment: You're definitely onto something! I think adding the second capture group was needed: `"gjhfgfcttttdfs".scan /((\p{alpha})\2{2,})/ #=> [["tttt", "t"]]`, but is it possible to do this with a single capture group? Trying to make one of the groups non-capturing doesn't work because you need the back-reference to the single letter, which then creates work to strip the second result in the sub-arrays. I guess this is what #match is doing under the hood anyway, making it a better choice. It just bothers me a bit that I can't extract the repeated characters without additional chaining on #scan.

Comment: You can mix named and unnamed captures to get the opposite of your after (`"aaabccc".scan(/((?<c>\p{alpha})\k<c>{2,})/)`) but mixing the capture types the other way around raises a `SyntaxError`, once you introduce named captures back references only work with named captures.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods are different in regards to their return values: `match` returns / yields [`MatchData`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/MatchData.html) objects whereas `scan` returns / yields strings which correspond to the content of capture groups (if present). `scan`'s behavior can be somehow inconvenient but you can work around it.

If you want the whole `MatchData` object (the way `match` works) but for each match, you can call `scan` with a block and use [`$~`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Regexp+Global+Variables) (or `Regexp.last_match`) to retrieve it:

```
"aaabccc".scan(/(\p{alpha})\1{2,}/) { p $~ }
# #<MatchData "aaa" 1:"a">
# #<MatchData "ccc" 1:"c">
```

To get an *array* of `MatchData` objects, you can utilize [`enum_for`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Object.html#method-i-enum_for) to get an "each match" enumerator and then `map` them to their respective `MatchData` via `$~`:

```
"aaabccc".enum_for(:scan, /(\p{alpha})\1{2,}/).map { $~ }
#=> [#<MatchData "aaa" 1:"a">, #<MatchData "ccc" 1:"c">]
```